# Ajax function over image

Tags: jquery, ajax, thumbnails

i want to launch a function on image over.
I use JQueryThumbGallery with lightbox and i want to retrive the image id

My code is

```
<div class='thumbHolder' **data-id="MY-ID"** data-title="<?php echo '<span class=\'io_home\'>'.$row['io'].'</span><br /> '.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].'<br/><span class=\'voti_home\'>'.$row['tot_voti'].' VOTI</span>'; ?>">
  <a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="index.php/image/view_image?ajax=true&width=700px&height=450px&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
  <img class="thumb_hidden" src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/concorso1/thumb/'.$row['url']; ?>" width="151" height="120" alt="<?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']; ?>" />
                                </a>

                            </div>
```

and the jquery function is

```
        function overThumb(i,j){

        //function called when mouse over thumb holder (plus returned item number: i = first level, j = second level)
        console.log('overThumb: ', i,' , ', j);
    }
```

I need to retrieve ID from the image on which I turn on (overThumb function). I have tried to set data-id-i and data-id-j but I haven’t understud how I should use them. Can you help me?

link to script

http://www.interactivepixel.net/ccThumbGallery/index_grid_horizontal_100percent_buttons.html

Thanks
fc

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP code to render the img tag markup like this (only HTML !no function hooked up)

```
<img class="thumb_hidden" src="Somepath/someimage.jpg" 
               data-myAttr="my custom val" id="someUniqueID" alt="some text" />
```

Now use some [unobutrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $("img.thumb_hidden").mouseover(function() {
       var ourImg=$(this);
       var urlOfImage=ourImg.attr("href");
       var idOfImage=ourImg.attr("id");
       //let's get the HTML5 data attribute as well
       var myCustomVal=ourImg.data("myAttr");
       //Now use these to make ajax call as necessary
   });    
 });
</script>
```